# multiline search and replace in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need some help in replacing a specific string using perl command, but the catch is that I need to replace this string only from the relevant tag and leave it as is in all other tags

my text file looks like this

```
[myTag]
some values 
and more values
my_string_To_Replace
some more values

[anotherTag]
more values
my_string_To_Replace

I did try below but this command replaces last occurrence only

Thanks
```

```
perl -p -i'.backup' -e 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(\[myTag\].*)(my_string_To_Replace)(.*)/$1NewString$3/smg' myText.file
```

```
      I'm expecting below results
[myTag]
some values 
and more values
NewString
some more values

[anotherTag]
more values
my_string_To_Replace
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: <pre>
[myTag]
some values 
and more values
NewString
some more values

[anotherTag]
more values
my_string_To_Replace

Comment: add the above to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would do like this,

```
$ perl -00pe 's/\[myTag\].*?\Kmy_string_To_Replace/NewString/gs' file
[myTag]
some values 
and more values
NewString
some more values

[anotherTag]
more values
my_string_To_Replace
```

`\K` discards previously matched characters and `-00` enables paragraph slurp mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok without a one liner, this should do the trick. Using the record delimiter to detect if you're between `[myTag]` and `^$` e.g. a blank line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
     if ( m/\[myTag\]/ .. /^$/ ) {
          s/my_string_To_Replace/some_other_text/;
     }
     print;        
}


__DATA__
[myTag]
some values 
and more values
my_string_To_Replace
some more values

[anotherTag]
more values
my_string_To_Replace
```

If you really want a 'one liner':

```
perl -p -i.bak -ne " if ( m/\[myTag\]/ .. /^$/ ) { s/my_string_To_Replace/some_other_text/; } " file.txt
```

Comment: I need to run it from command line and not as a perl script :(

Comment: If you're typing it in by hand, then you're doing it wrong. If you're _not_ typing it in by hand, then you don't need a one liner.  But this mechanism should still work inlined.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it with a small difference than what was suggested by Avinish Raj

```
perl -p -i'.backup' -e 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/\[myTag\].*?\Kmy_string_To_Replace/NewString/gs' myFile
```